# Error package 'sqlite3>=3.7.11' not found

Tags: cmake, sqlite3

I clone a project from github and run cmake, but I get the message:

```
-- checking for module 'sqlite3>=3.7.11'
--   package 'sqlite3>=3.7.11' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/Modules/FindSqlite3.cmake:22 (pkg_check_modules)
  src/components/utils/src/sqlite_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:33 (find_package)


-- Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
```

My sqlite3 has version:

```
 sqlite3 --version
3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
```

I already install `libsqlite3-dev`.

The code to check `sqlite`:

```
if (SQLITE3_LIBRARIES AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  set(SQLITE3_FOUND TRUE)
else (SQLITE3_LIBRARIES AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  find_package(PkgConfig)
  if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    pkg_check_modules(_SQLITE3 REQUIRED sqlite3>=3.7.11)
  else (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    message(WARNING "PkgConfig isn't installed. You need to sure sqlite3>=3.7.11")
  endif (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --modversion sqlite3`?

Comment: 3.7.9. Thanks for your comment. I will fix it.